# How to delete all disabled webhooks in WooCommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I have a WooCommerce store with over 200,000 disabled webhooks that I need to delete. I initially tried to remove these webhooks using the WooCommerce REST API and the command line, with the following bash script:

```
response=$(curl -u consumer_key:consumer_secret https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/webhooks)
ids=$(echo $response | jq -r '.[].id')

for id in $ids
do
 curl -u consumer_key:consumer_secret -X DELETE https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/webhooks/$id
done
```

(Note: In the actual command, I replace consumer_key, consumer_secret, and mywebsite.com with my actual API keys and website URL.)

Unfortunately, this script did not return any webhook IDs, despite there being visible disabled webhooks in the WooCommerce webhooks settings page (WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Webhooks).

To further investigate the issue, I attempted to run the curl and jq commands separately:

```
response=$(curl -u consumer_key:consumer_secret https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wc/v3/webhooks)
echo $response
```

However, this just returned speed and time information from the curl command, without outputting any webhook data.

Additionally, I attempted to delete these disabled webhooks directly from the MySQL database using the PHPMyAdmin interface, with this query:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_webhook' AND post_status = 'draft';
```

Again, this did not work as expected and returned an empty result set, indicating that no rows were deleted.

I am at a loss as to why I'm unable to delete these disabled webhooks using either method. Does anyone have any insights or alternative suggestions on how I might effectively remove these disabled webhooks from my WooCommerce store? Is there something I'm missing with either the REST API calls or the SQL query? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce Webhooks are not located in `wp_post` table.

They have their own table: wp_wc_webhooks

The possible statuses for web hooks are: 'active', 'paused' or 'disabled'.

The correct simple working SQL Query to delete all "disabled" webhooks is:

```sql
DELETE FROM wp_wc_webhooks WHERE status = 'disabled';
```

> Take care to change the table prefix `wp_` if required